# Generate view from a dynamic model

Tags: java, swing, oop, model-view-controller, polymorphism

I have a model which can be modified at run time. Here's an example :

```
public class JavaMethod
{
   private String            name;
   private List<Parameter>   parameters;
   private boolean           isConstructor; // this is an example
}
```

The parameters can have different type (`integer`, `boolean`, `string`, `float`...) and different valid values. For example, an integer parameter named *age* could only hold positive integers.

The problem is that I would like to generate a view with Swing to configure that `JavaMethod`object, but I am not sure of the proper way to do it.

For example, the *age* parameter which is a positive integer would be linked to a class extending `JTextField` that prevent entering negative any letters. Another integer parameter named *numberOfFingers* which can range from 8 to 12 would be linked to a class extending `JComboBox` that allows selection of an option in that range.

I could do this with polymorphism by giving the task of generating the appropriate Swing component to the Parameter object, but then my model would know about how the view is generated.

What is the proper way of generating a view for a model like this?
All I can think of (without the model involved in the generation of the view) is a  kind of giant switch in the controller that picks the good component by reading the Parameter's details.

Thanks

Comment: I would do a search for "Java property sheet" and see what you come up with

Comment: Thanks, I am in fact making a property sheet for the model object.

Comment: Think a little along the lines of how the table/tree API works. Basically, you want to register renderer/editor component to your view. This would allow the view to inspect the parameter type and decide how best to render/edit the value. You would then, obviously need to decide on best course of action to define default implementations for the most common data types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is to use the Visitor Pattern.

For example :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Main
{
    public static class JavaMethod implements Iterable<Parameter>
    {
        private List<Parameter> parameters;

        public JavaMethod()
        {
            this.parameters = new ArrayList<>();
            // This is an example
            this.parameters.add(new IntegerParameter());
            this.parameters.add(new StringParameter());
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<Parameter> iterator()
        {
            return this.parameters.iterator();
        }
    }

    public static interface Parameter
    {
        public void accept(ParameterVisitor visitor);
    }

    public static class IntegerParameter implements Parameter
    {
        public int value = 10;

        @Override
        public void accept(final ParameterVisitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }

    public static class StringParameter implements Parameter
    {
        public String value = "Hello";

        @Override
        public void accept(final ParameterVisitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }

    public static interface ParameterVisitor
    {
        void visit(StringParameter stringParameter);
        void visit(IntegerParameter integerParameter);
    }

    public static class ParameterSwingVisitor implements ParameterVisitor
    {
        private final JComponent container;

        public ParameterSwingVisitor(final JComponent container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(final StringParameter stringParameter)
        {
            this.container.add(new JTextField(stringParameter.value));
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(final IntegerParameter integerParameter)
        {
            // This could be a custom component to pick numbers
            this.container.add(new JLabel(String
                    .valueOf(integerParameter.value)));
        }

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(); // view
                JavaMethod myMethod = new JavaMethod(); // model

                final ParameterVisitor visitor = new ParameterSwingVisitor(
                        myPanel);

                for (final Parameter picked : myMethod)
                {
                    picked.accept(visitor); // This will add the appropriate
                                            // swing
                                            // component
                }

                JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Visitor pattern");
                myFrame.setContentPane(myPanel);
                myFrame.setVisible(true);
                myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                myFrame.setSize(500, 500);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

More information about this pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

For that you are needed to create Customized `PlainDocument` . For example for `JTextField` containing only age value you should create `AgeDocument` class which would look something like this :

```
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
class AgeDocument extends PlainDocument 
{
    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException 
    {
        /**Write your logic here**/
        if (str == null) 
        {
            return;
        }
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (!Character.isDigit(arr[i]))//Checking for Non Numeric.
            {
                return;
            }
            if (Character.getNumericValue(arr[i])==0 )
            {
                try
                {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(getText(0,offs));
                    if (val == 0) 
                    {
                        super.insertString(offs,"", a);//Don't allow to put 0 as age.
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex){return;}
            }
        }
        super.insertString(offs, new String(str), a);
    }
}
```

And whenever you want to set this `AgeDocument` property to a `JTextField` object you simply write `JTextFieldOBject.setDocument(new AgeDocument ())`

Likewise , you can create many model independently. And can use them anywhere in your code.

Comment: That could be useful, thanks. But before using this technique to filter the input, I have to initialize the view with the appropriate components. Where and how should I be picking a `JTextField`, a `JComboBox` or any other component associated with the `Parameter`'s type and condition. Should this all go into a big switch `if(param.isInt() && param.isRange()){ createComboBox(); }` with a case for every type?

Comment: If you sure of the components of `swing` that would be invoked on given input type , then you could create a `Map` having `key` as the type of parameter and `value` as the name of class of `Swing` `component` whose object you want to create for corresponding key. This way you could easily find out the actual component to be created corresponding to given type of parameter using `get(key)` method of `Map`.. IMO